# Log4j2: How do I get timestamps that actually have nanosecond precision?

Tags: timestamp, log4j2

In https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout, it described how to format the log timestamp with up to nanosecond precision.
Further, in http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#SystemProperties, it is said that the default time stamp is taken from `System.getCurrentTimeMillis()` and that if you want a different clock, you should set the property `log4j2.clock` in `log4j2.component.properties` to the fully qualified class name of a class implementing `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.Clock`.
Looking in https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/index.html, I see that said interface allows only millisecond precision, but it has a sub-interface `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.time.PreciseClock` that allows for nanosecond precision. I have implemented a class

```
package my.package;
import java.time.Instant;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.time.MutableInstant;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.time.PreciseClock;

/**
 * Provides the current time up to nanosecond precision, as supported by the platform.
 * Note that most current platforms provide only microsecond precision.
 */
public class NanoSecondClock implements PreciseClock {
    /**
     * Returns the time in milliseconds since the epoch.
     * @return the time in milliseconds since the epoch.
     */
    public long currentTimeMillis(){return System.currentTimeMillis();}
    /**
     * Initializes the specified instant with time information as accurate as available on this platform.
     * @param mutableInstant The container to be initialized with the accurate time information.
     */
    public void init(MutableInstant mutableInstant){
        Instant now=Instant.now();
        mutableInstant.initFromEpochSecond(now.getEpochSecond(),now.getNano());
    }
}
```

This class provides both millisecond and nanosecond precision as it must to implement the interface. I have set the above mentioned property to that class.
Now, in my logs I see only millisecond precision timestamps, even though I have tested that my platform supports microsecond precision in `Instant.now()`.

Did I overlook something?

Answer (score 0):

You can put a breakpoint into `o.a.l.l.core.util.ClockFactory#createClock()` to see what is missing in your configuration. In a nutshell, setting the `log4j.clock=my.package.NanoSecondClock` system property should simply work.

Please take into account that the date-time formatting is one of the most time consuming operations in the lifetime of a log event. Log4j pulls various tricks under the hood to make it perform good. There caching plays a crucial role. By increasing the time precision, you void such caching opportunities. I would strongly advise you to reassess your need for nanosecond-precision timestamps in logs.

Comment: The need for finer-than-millisecond granularity arises from the need to make the timestamps unique, such that the messages can be stored in a database and retrieved in the right order. This obviously precludes caching.